# Trying to get regex pattern to match any other than letters and single special character

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm new to regex and am trying to match a very simple pattern but am struggling to get regex. I basically just want test a bunch of strings to check if they contain anything that isn't either in 'a-z' (both lower or upper case) or '_' character. So if a string contains the '@' character I want it to fail.

so far it looks like:

```
if (!preg_match("/[a-z_]/", $string)) {
     echo "Bad string";
}
```

But that's failing to pickup anything it seems. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/wKUNjm/2  `[^a-zA-Z_]`

Comment: Here is an example `if(filter_var($field, FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array("options"=>array("regexp"=>"/^[a-zA-Z]*$/")))){
        return $field;
    } else{
        return FALSE;
    }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use negation in your regex to search for characters you don't want.

```
// If the string has any characters other than A-z or _ then echo bad string
if (preg_match("/[^a-zA-Z_]/", $string)) {
     echo "Bad string";
}
```

https://regex101.com/r/wKUNjm/2